# operator "it" in kotlin. PopupMenu(this, it)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this line of code and I can not find any information what does mean operator "it" which is in brackets. How does "it" usually used?
val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, it)

The tutorial where I found this line of code (time - 3:20) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncHjCsoj0Ws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it` is an [implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)

> It's very common that a lambda expression has only one parameter.
>
> If the compiler can figure the signature out itself, it is allowed not
>   to declare the only parameter and omit `->`. The parameter will be
>   implicitly declared under the name `it`

In your example `it` means the view that was clicked